# How do I use X509Certificate2 for mutual SSL in .NET? Private key is not recognized

Tags: .net, x509, x509certificate2

So, I have a private key, and a certificate in 2 files... I need to feed that to X509Certificate2 to use for mutual SSL. When I simply do `new X509Certificate2` - I can specify one file name. I created .pem file with both, but `cert.HasPrivateKey` shows FALSE.

What would be the format in which both will be in one file, and X509Certificate2 would understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A p12/pkcs12/pfx file has both private key and certificate

An example of using this is:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2(@"C:\Path\my.pfx", "password");
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I needed. Converted my files to PFX, and it worked. Thanks!